# Mouse not working and many UI errors after 12.04 upgrade

Tags: unity, upgrade

Upgraded from 10.x or 11.x and I'm having lots of problems.

All icons in the dock are gone, as well as most other icons:

[image: monochrome dash]

No icons, applications can't be focused, no window chrome (title bar etc):

[image: file brower]

Additionally, the mouse pointer isn't moving. It works fine under Win XP.

Is there a way to repair Ubuntu? And keep all application settings etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your upgrade has gone wrong. Boot into recovery mode from your Grub menu, enter a root shell and run:

```
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get install -f
```

Comment: Running `dpkg --configure -a` generated lots of dependency issues, but after I ran `apt-get install -f` everything worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

choose dpkg from the recovery menu. Allow to unmount and remount the filesystem with read/write permission.
Once it's done choose root from the menu and enter the command 
apt-get install -f 
Reboot after it's done.